# A function and its tangent map

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Say we have two smooth manifolds and a map $F$ between them with corresponding tangent map $dF$.

Next consider the set of curves on this manifold or equivalently
the set of smooth sections of the tangent bundle.

Now $F$ maps sets i.e images of curves while $dF$ maps the curves via the associated section of the tangent bundle. Hence the two functions $F$ and $dF$ really contains the same information in some sense.

Am I on to some fundamental idea of having tangetspaces with this observation or is it complete nonsense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this is definitely not nonsense, but I would not say they contain the same information. The tangent map is defined locally, so we should really write $dF_p$, and it encodes the infinitesimal information (or linear approximation) about the map $F$ in a neighborhood of the point $p$. Also worthy of note is that while $dF_p$ is always defined locally, one cannot always map a global vector field on a manifold $M$ to a global vector field on a manifold $N$. It can always be done if $F$ is a diffeomorphism, but if the map is not injective, we might end up with two tangent vectors at the same point. [This wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)) has more info about what the tangent map $dF$ really represents.

Also I don't understand what you mean by the set of curves on a manifold is equivalent to the sections of the tangent bundle. The sections are smooth global vector fields, and while they are intimately related (by integral flows), I would not say they are equivalent. In fact, if you have a curve in a manifold, you can in many cases define different smooth vector fields along that curve.

Comment: Isnt the "tangent fields" since we take sections from the tangent bundle the same as the curves?

Comment: Nope, think about a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and a smooth vector field along that curve as an arrow sticking out from that curve (with the head of the arrow staying in the plane) at every point in a "smooth way" (to make that precise, see any introductory differential geometry book), clearly there are many ways to do so, and each one corresponds to a section of the pullback of the tangent bundle over the curve. A great resource for this is Tu's Differential Geometry, page 180.

Comment: Isnt there only one tanget to the curve at each point? well up to length scaling.

Comment: Ah, that is true, but there is a difference between the tangent bundle of the curve and a vector field along a curve. Say $C$ is a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $C(0) = p$, then you are correct in saying that $T_p C$ is a 1 dimensional vector space.

Comment: But, $T_p \mathbb{R}^2$ is a 2 dimensional vector space, in fact it is an exact copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the origin at the point $p$. If I think of the tangent bundle $T \mathbb{R}^2$ as a set of tuples $(p,v)$ where $p$ is a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $v$ is a vector in $T_p \mathbb{R}^2$, then I can consider only the points along $C$, but where the vectors are in $T_p \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: And this would correspond to a section of the pullback bundle $C^* T \mathbb{R}^2$. But this isn't so related to your question, I was just trying to show that the relationship between the curves in a manifold and the sections of a tangent bundle of the manifold is not as simple as you made it out to be.

Comment: but under special circumstances they are?